# Simple Matrix Similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

For a matrix

\begin{array}{cc}
   a & 0 \\
   0 & b \\
  \end{array}

and 
\begin{array}{cc}
   b & 0 \\
   0 & a \\
  \end{array}
how do we prove if they are similar? They have the same characteristic polynomial, and same rank. Are there other attributes of similar matrices that might confirm their similarity? If not, how can we prove they aren't similar? I wasn't sure how to use the A = $P^{-1}$BP characteristic of similar matrices.

Comment: Hint: since they both have full rank (assuming $a,b\neq 0$), the image of the two linearly independent vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ under both matrices must be linearly independent.

Comment: Try using $P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are similar. Just take $P=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and check that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}b&0\\0&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]=P.\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right].P^{-1}$.